# Creating simple kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, c

I've just started learning linux kernel modules and trying to write simple Hello world program.

So mymod.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Author");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("\"Hello, world!\" minimal module");
MODULE_VERSION("printk");

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("<1>Hello world 1.\n");
    return 0;
} 

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += mymod.o 
all:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules 
clean: 
     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

make outout:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic-pae/build M=/root modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-3.2.42'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/src/linux-3.2.42/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-3.2.42'
```

So it creates files I needed, but when I try to install this by

```
insmod mymod.ko
```

I get next output:

```
insmod: error inserting 'mymod.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

So I'd like to know what's the problem?

PS. OS - Ubuntu Server 12.04. Kernel - linux 3.2.0-23 pae

UPDATE:

I've downloaded from kernel.org kernel 3.2.42 and put it in /usr/src and did 'make defconfig && make prepare', 'make modules_prepare'. Also I've created link in /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic-pae/build.

Comment: Any error reported in `dmesg`?

Comment: Have you actually compiled a kernel in that src tree?

Comment: @Sukminder No difference between `module_init(function)` or `init_module()` etc. Also I've tried module_init - same result

Comment: Minimal runnable example on Ubuntu 16.04: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d45ceace5d6ea114d9fab0dca1e66d08b64661ba/host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the source tree for the running kernel? If not, it *should* fail.

Install the kernel-devel (or similarly named) package for your distribution, it adds enough machinery to build modules against it.

Comment: while compiling kernel I got error 'Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again'. On some forum I found that I need to install libncurses5. So I've installed it and compilation finished with output as in my question.

Comment: kernel-devel is package for Fedora. For Ubuntu I've installed module-assistant

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `module_init` and `module_cleanup` declaration,

```
module_init (module_init);
module_exit (cleanup_module);
```

Otherwise it would have no entry point defined, and it wouldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Because this task requires so many details, and small files to be coordinated it is best to use UML (user mode linux) so that the kprintf (kernel printf) always outputs to the terminal even in a graphical environment.